# Add plugin-proposal-class-properties to create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, package.json

I created a react project using `create-react-app`.
Now when I add a certain dependency in `package.json` I get an error after running `npm start`:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled.
Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

I tried to use `npm run eject` and then do `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` but that is not working even if I update the babel part in the `package.json` with:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

What am I missing? I tried the solutions already proposed in this forum but they are not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-app-rewired to override webpack.